# VBA Select Case two variables

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use select case to determine a pay raise based on employee code and number of years employed. I am having a hard time using select case with two variables. Below is my code:

```
'declare variables
Dim strCode As String
Dim strYears As String
Dim intYears As Integer
Dim sngRaise As Single

'enter employee code and years employed
strCode = InputBox(prompt:="Enter the employee code: ", Title:="Code")
strYears = InputBox(prompt:="Enter the number of years employed: ", _
   Title:="Years")

'convert years to a number and convert code to uppercase
intYears = Val(strYears)
strCode = UCase(strCode)

'assign raise rate
Select Case True
Case Is = "A" And strYears >= 3
    sngRaise = 0.04
Case "B" And strYears >= 5
    sngRaise = 0.05
Case Else
    sngRaise = 0.03
End Select

MsgBox prompt:=Format(expression:=sngRaise, Format:="percent"), _
Buttons:=vbOKOnly + vbInformation, Title:="Raise Rate"


End Sub
```

I am trying to make it that all Code 3 employees and all employees who have been with the company for five years are to receive a 5% raise and employees having other job codes or those who have been with the company for less than 5 years get a 4.5% raise. I seem to have got Code 3 and employees who have been with the company for five years to run correctly, however, I am stuck on how to code "all other job codes" and exclude job Code 3 from it. Below is my code

```
'declare variables
 Dim intCode As Integer
 Dim strYears As String
 Dim intYears As Integer
 Dim sngRaise As Single

 'enter employee code and years employed
 intCode = InputBox(prompt:="Enter the employee 
 code: ", Title:="Code")
 strYears = InputBox(prompt:="Enter the number of 
  years employed: ", _
 Title:="Years")

'convert years to a number
 intYears = Val(strYears)

'assign raise rate
 Select Case True
 Case intCode = "3" Or strYears >= 5
sngRaise = 0.05
 Case intCode = 1 To 2 Or strYears <= 5
sngRaise = 0.045

End Select

MsgBox prompt:=Format(expression:=sngRaise, 
Format:="percent"), _
Buttons:=vbOKOnly + vbInformation, Title:="Raise 
Rate"
```

Comment: You need to be careful when combining 2 variables (to get the combination correct). In your case: `Case strCode = "A" And strYears >= 3` etc. Note you should convert the types at the InputBox line.

Comment: A useful search phrase for you might be `select case vba`, which should find you examples of the proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, you doesn't have to use the case statement.

```
Dim raise(3, 2)  'job code, year less then 5/greater than 5

raise(1, 1) = 0.045
raise(1, 2) = 0.05
raise(2, 1) = 0.045
raise(2, 2) = 0.05
raise(3, 1) = 0.05
raise(3, 2) = 0.05


intCode = InputBox(prompt:="Enter the employee  code: ", Title:="Code")
strYears = InputBox(prompt:="Enter the number of years employed: ", Title:="Years")

If (intYears >= 5) Then
    intYears = 2
Else
    intYears = 1
End If

MsgBox ("The percentage of raise is: " & raise(intCode, intYears))
```